# Brand new project giving resource error on creation in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

As soon as I create a Android project in Eclipse Indigo I instantly get a resource error on the line, setContentView(R.layout.main);  To make it worse, projects that were working now are having their 'gen' folder emptied upon being built...

Unfortunately using google gives me a million references to projects that need to have files renamed or rebuilt, so I thought I'd ask here.

***UPDATE***
I've tried cleaning the project, I've double checked all the resource files, I've restarted Eclipse, and restarted the machine, but nothing has fixed it yet.
***END UPDATED***

Thanks in advance,
eimmer

Comment: Make sure the main file exists in the layout folder. Then clean the project. See if it works.

Comment: clean and bulid your project.it will solve your problem.it its not work then restart the eclipse then check if its work.hope this helps.

Comment: Checked all the resource files and even deleted and recreated my "main" layout file, but still did not work.

Comment: Cleaned and rebuilt, but did not work either.

Comment: hi did you updated your ADT to 22 ?

Comment: @eimmer Can you post the content of the `main` file?

Comment: @Shobhit Puri, not the main file, but good idea.

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys I was on 22, upgraded to 22.0.1 and now everything works! Thanks for leading me that way!

Answer (score 1):

If you are updated your ADT to 22 means below trick will work.

Right **Click Project-> Propertis-> Java Build Path-> order/export Tab -> (Tick) Android Private Libraries Click Ok and save**. Now clean the project. Your errors will get clear.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue had to due with ADT 22, but this was not the problem.  Thanks for the thought, it led me to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if main.xml is in layout folder.
2. Try : Right click project -> Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties.

Comment: This has worked for me before, but not this time.  Still giving me a resource error...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone.  Opened the Android SDK Manager and saw  Android SDK Tools 22.0.1 under tools. Installed that and it fixed whatever was wrong...